# How can I convert a JTextField that's returning null to a different string value?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField that I'm not always passing a value to, but it causes a NumberFormatException error to be thrown when the program runs if the person hasn't entered anything into the JTextField. I have some code below that I'm trying to convert a null response into a different String value. Why isn't it assigning stringInput as a String of "0"?

```
public int getOptionalDinners()
{
  try
  {     
  // get the input from the text field and determine if it's more than 0
  String stringInput = " ";
  stringInput = dinnerTextField.getText();
  if (stringInput == null)
     stringInput = "0";
  int validAmount = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);
  if (validAmount < 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  dinnerQuantity = validAmount * 30;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException error)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The number of dinners needs to be numeric.", 
           "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException error)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The number of dinners needs to be higher than 0.", 
           "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

  return dinnerQuantity;
}
```

Comment: And the stack trace? Which exception is thrown, and where?

Comment: java.lang.Exception
OptionalDinners.getOptionalDinners(OptionalDinners.java:70)
RegistrationGUI$CalcButtonListener.actionPerformed(RegistrationGUI.java:90)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

Comment: I added new Exception().printStackTrace(); to line 70, inside the first catch block.

Comment: You're essentially swallowing the exception, making it very hard to see what the problem is. Creating a new Exception only to see the stack trace isn't all that helpful. Consider logging the error or doing error.printStackTrace() instead. Anyways, in this case it seems you're getting a NumberFormatException, which happens if you try to convert a non-number (such as the empty string) to an int.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (stringInput == null || stringInput.length() == 0)  {
  stringInput = "0";
}
```

You also need to check if it is 0 length.

Then assign the value back to the JTextField.

```
dinnerTextField.setText(stringInput);
```

Comment: using .length tells me that it can't find symbol: length

Comment: .length()  have a bracket since it is a String function not a property.

Comment: heh, thanks. All I needed to do was add the () onto length (I tried using length already).

Answer (score 0):

you can change the below line:

```
if (stringInput == null)
```

to

```
if (stringInput == null || stringInput == "")
```

Comment: that still causes the exception to be thrown